# How to load kubeconfig file from S3 using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I am using kubernetes provider with terraform. Config_path attribute refers to config file in my local machine and with that i am able to auth to my cluster.

I want to achieve the same with something like travis ci. Instead of storing file as base64 secret, is it possible to load kube config file from s3 bucket?
Please help...

Comment: Try using the [S3 bucket data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html) to read your config file from the S3 bucket. You'll need to configure a data source for the bucket and file that you want to read, then use that resource as an argument to the kubernetes provider.

Then pass the value with something like `data.aws_s3_bucket_object.kubeconfig.body`.

However, it looks like the kubernetes provider wants a path. How are you specifying it with base64?

Comment: Well, i am storing base64 encoded as a secret and then decoding into a file and using path of local file. However, i dont feel that a secure solution, i think encrypting and storing in s3 is much better.